# Aligning center to the middle of an image in a table cell?

Tags: image, alignment

I have this HTML:

```
<td>
    <ol start="4">
        <li>
            <div style="float:left;">some text</div>
            <div style="float:right;">
                <img style="vertical-align:middle;" src="pic.png" />
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</td>
```

I tried lots of things including vertical-align:middle to either align the text to the middle of the image or the other way round, nothing changed the result. So far, the top of the image is aligned with the top of the text.

Whats wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your "some text" div inside the pic div, set it to `display:inline` so it wont break line and just add the `vertical-align:middle` , like so:

```
<table><tr>
<td>
    <ol start="4">
        <li>

            <div style="float:right;">
                <div style="display:inline;vertical-align:middle;">some text</div>
                <img style="vertical-align:middle;" src="pic.png" />
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

Working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EALxE/)

**UPDATE**:
To be able to do `vertical-align:middle` on several lines breaked by `<br>`, as OP noted in comments, change the display of "some text" div to `inline-table` instead of just `inline`, see working [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a4fGa/1/)

Comment: This goes into the right direction, but now the 4. from the list is still at the old position. It needs to go down a bit, too.

Comment: You are commenting issues I don't see in the code you pasted, try making a http://jsfiddle.net testcase of the issues you are describing so we can help you more.

Comment: You are right, please take alook here: http://jsfiddle.net/a4fGa/. The text needs to be left of the image. Forget what I said in the first comment.

Comment: Ok, and what is wrong in the jsfiddle you posted? what do you want to change in it?

Comment: One line of the text is above the image and the other is left of it. I want both lines to be left of the image.